# Why do single quotes prevent parameter replacement in prepared queries?

Tags: php, pdo

I spent some time chasing a bug in my code, and I found the issue. I was using prepared statements and using an array to replace the parameters. My issue was that by enclosing the named parameter in the prepared query, it prevent the parameter from being replaced.

Here is some sample code:

```
try {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pass);                                                                                                                                      
} catch(PDOException $e) {                                                                                                                                                                              
    echo $e->getMessage();                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       

function insert_update_db($query, $params = NULL) {                                                                                                                                                     
global $conn;                                                                                                                                                                                           
    try {                                                                                                                                                                                               
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);                                                                                                                                                                  
        $sql->execute($params);                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    catch(PDOException $e) {                                                                                                                                                                            
        echo $e->getMessage();                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
$params = array(":a" => 1, ":b" => "test_string");                                                                                                                                                      
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (:a, :b)";                                                                                                                                                          
insert_update_db($query, $params);                                                                                                                                                            
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (':a', ':b')";                                                                                                                                                      
insert_update_db($query, $params);
```

From the general log:

```
Query INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('1', 'test_string')
Query INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (':a', ':b')
```

As you can see from the general log, the second query does not replace the parameters. Why does that happen?

Comment: If it's in quotes it's a literal, not a parameter, so shouldn't be replaced. What if you need to insert the literal string ':a', and also happen to have a parameter labelled :a in the same query? Without the distinction between what's a parameter and what isn't, you wouldn't be able to

Comment: Does that mean that parameters should never be enclosed in quotes? I just tried escaping single quotes and double quotes and saw the same behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the escaping, but yes, parameters should never be quoted. The DB engine (or PDO Itself in a pinch) take care of that for you

Answer (score 1):

The `prepare` method is analyzing the SQL query string looking for the replacements (:var or ?). The quoted values are not replaced, otherwise you wouldn't be able to store a literal ':b' value in a table field.
Here you have further information about `PDO::prepare`
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php